# Bootstrap "grunt watch" wont create bootstrap.min.css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, watch

I am almost absolutely new to grunt.
I used grunt with bootstrap 3.1.1 and the `grunt watch`-command worked out great. My bootstrap.min.css file was compiled every time. (i upload my bootstrap.min.css)

Later on i lost my 3.1.1 grunt file (long story short my computer crashed).
So now with Bootstrap 3.2.0 i was going to restablish my grunt-work-flow.

But now when i use `grunt watch` i only get the "bootstrap.css" and "bootstrap.theme.css" compiled.

I have spent the last hours to figure this out without success.

**WHAT I WANT**
I want `grunt watch` to compile the minified "bootstrap.min.css"
So how do i call the min.css-function on the `watch`?

I will be glad to get some help.

Comment: can you post the contents of your gruntfile?

Comment: @msturdy thank you for taking a look, it is the standard gruntfile. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

Comment: You just read these 2 questions also....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833281/why-main-min-css-was-not-created-only-when-i-run-grunt-watch-command-but-its-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377700/how-to-add-build-property-to-watch-task-of-gruntjs-through-command-terminalro

Comment: You just read these 2 questions also.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833281/why-main-min-css-was-not-created-only-when-i-run-grunt-watch-command-but-its-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377700/how-to-add-build-property-to-watch-task-of-gruntjs-through-command-terminalro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grunt watch will only watch the files then run tasks you have set. I am assuming in your gruntfile you ahve something like this:

```
css: {
    files: [
      'bootstrap.css',
    ],
    tasks: ['less'],
  },
```

In the less task you should have something like below. Note the `cleancss` option being set to true:

```
options: {
      cleancss: true
    },

    files: {
      "dest/bootstrap.min.css": "src/bootstrap.css",
      "dest/bootstrap.theme.min.css": "src/bootstrap.theme.css"
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on the file you uploaded you should be running the `cssmin:core` task when the watch is triggered.

**UPDATE 2:**
To update the watch task you can just add the cssmin:core task to the less subtask:

```
less: {
        files: 'less/**/*.less',
        tasks: ['less', 'cssmin:core]
      }
```

Here you are telling it to run the less task, followed by the `cssmin` task whenever one of the less files is changed while watching.

Comment: I cannot find anything like `cleancss:` in my [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/Gruntfile.js). The files i want to be watched are being watched so that is all set. The min.css is not compiled/created.

Comment: Yes there is a cssmin:core but i have no `options:` for it that says `cleancss:`?

Comment: Yes sorry I was basing that off of a generic gruntfile configuration. The `cssmin:core` task is specifically for minification.
What you need is either to create a new watch task that runs `cssmin:core` after compiling the css files, or just run `grunt cssmin:core` manually from the terminal to minify the files.

Comment: Thank you. So, the `grunt dist` worsk just fine, then the cssmin is runned but i want it to be runned also within `watch`. Do you have an idéa of how to fix that?

Comment: Have updated my answer with how you can add `cssmin:core` to the watch task.

Comment: Gah, it whas that easy!? Thank you, i feel kind of stupid. But i am not familiar with the grunt syntax. Big thank you! @Guy

Comment: In Bootstrap 3.3.4 it's not `cssmin:core` rather then `cssmin:minifyCore`

Answer (score 1):

Your gruntfile.js will have a 'watch' section as below

```html
    watch: {
      src: {
        files: '<%= jshint.core.src %>',
        tasks: ['jshint:src', 'qunit', 'concat']
      },
      test: {
        files: '<%= jshint.test.src %>',
        tasks: ['jshint:test', 'qunit']
      },
      less: {
        files: 'less/**/*.less',
        tasks: 'less'
      }
    },
```

The tasks under less subsection define the tasks that 'grunt watch' will run. In Bootstrap 3.3.2 (I guess in 3.1.1 also it would be the same) is the 'cssmin' task that minifies the core bootstrap css. So you need to add the task to less so the code above becomes

```html
    watch: {
      src: {
        files: '<%= jshint.core.src %>',
        tasks: ['jshint:src', 'qunit', 'concat']
      },
      test: {
        files: '<%= jshint.test.src %>',
        tasks: ['jshint:test', 'qunit']
      },
      less: {
        files: 'less/**/*.less',
        tasks: ['less', 'cssmin']
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. Looks like the css minification command changed to `cssmin:minifyCore` so I have updated my watch task to the following:

```
watch: {
  src: {
    files: '<%= jshint.core.src %>',
    tasks: ['jshint:core', 'qunit', 'concat']
  },
  test: {
    files: '<%= jshint.test.src %>',
    tasks: ['jshint:test', 'qunit']
  },
  less: {
    files: 'less/**/*.less',
    tasks: ['less', 'cssmin:minifyCore']
  }
},
```

Hopefully this helps others!